# Spring MVC and Spring WS dispatcher servlet configuration in one web application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, soap

I trying to implement both spring rest and soap in same application .I configured two separate configurations for REST and SOAP.But im unable to start the server because im getting below exception 
"Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext".
Help me to define both dispatcher servlet in java config.

My classes :

REST API COnfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.test1.*" })
public class RestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(extendedJsonConvertor());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter extendedJsonConvertor() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
                .setObjectMapper(getNullAndEmptyFilteredObjectMapper());
        return mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the null and empty filtered object mapper.
     *
     */
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getNullAndEmptyFilteredObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       // objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);        
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
        return objectMapper;
    }



}
```

REST MVC COnfiguration:

```
public class RESTMvcConfiguration extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName() {
        return "REST";
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RestConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

SOAP COnfiguration:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.test1.*" })
public class SoapServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "country")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountryPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://test.*.*.com");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("country.xsd"));
    }
}
```

SOAP MVC COnfiguration:

```
public class SoapMvcConfiguration extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName() {
        return "SOAP";
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { SoapServiceConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    }
```

Exception

```
01:14:51.978 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG c.a.c.c.RESTMvcConfiguration - No ContextLoaderListener registered, as createRootApplicationContext() did not return an application context
01:14:52.104 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG c.a.c.s.c.SoapMvcConfiguration - No ContextLoaderListener registered, as createRootApplicationContext() did not return an application context
May 05, 2016 1:14:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TEST]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TEST]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5580)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in your configuration `yourConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` class.

You map the two configurations getServletMappings under web root path.

A better approach will be to have a getServletMappings path for your rest api and another for ws api and another for page serving if you need, like below:

```
    public class SoapMvcConfiguration extends
            AbstractAnnotationConfigMessageDispatcherServletInitializer{

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected String getServletName() {
            return "soap";
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[] { SoapServiceConfiguration.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/ws/*" };
        }
    }

    public class RestMvcConfiguration extends
            AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected String getServletName() {
            return "rest";
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[] { RestConfiguration.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/api/*" };
        }

    }
```

you should not use ServletRegistrationBean Bean because this bean is for Spring boot. If you use Boot you should use the built in and don't configure AbstractAnnotationConfigMessageDispatcherServletInitializer. it is better use the built in AbstractAnnotationConfigMessageDispatcherServletInitializer of spring boot.

this is my soap config class:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.ws")
public class SoapServiceConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition country(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);

        definition.setPortTypeName("Country");
        definition.setLocationUri("http://wstest/uri");
        definition.setTargetNamespace("http://wstest");

        return definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema countriesSchema() {
        System.out.println("CONFIG");

        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("country.xsd"));
    }
}
```

this is my xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://wstest"
           targetNamespace="http://wstest" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getCountryRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="getCountryResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="country" type="tns:country"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="country">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="population" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="capital" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and this is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled6</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>untitled6</name>

    <properties>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</source>
                </sources>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

In my config I don't use Spring boot
I hope that this can help you

Comment: Im still getiing the same exception .Updated the full stack trace in the post.Thank you

Comment: of nothing ;) it was a pleasure for me

Comment: @ValerioVaudi - is there a way to control the order of which Servlet is called first? In my case the default is a SOAP endpoint mapped to '/*' so I need to ensure the API endpoint '/api' is checked first, else default to the SOAP. Is this possible with a tweak to the solution above? Thanks